# What is common practices for wrong ClientCredentials?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl

I have WCF service hosted on local IIS under SSL. 
It seems to be working with SL client. But I stuck on user authentication. 
I have login screen with textboxes for user name and password. Once user click on login button something must happen, but what? I saw a lot of examples where are setting up ClientCredentials is the last step. What I suppose to do if user enter bad credentials? 
The exception is throwing after calling some operation. I get not a fault exception I had thrown, but CommunicationException.

```
public class UserAuthentication : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                throw new FaultException("Invalid user name or password");
            }
    }
```

Also ClientCredentials became read only after calling some operation. So I have to refresh it some how. I was thinking to replace endpoint behavior, but I'm not sure is it good idea.

So, basically my main question is: "What I suppose to do if user enter bad credentials?"

Comment: Anyone? I'm sure that some approach is exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of authentication when it comes to WCF.

First, you can create authentication that works BEFORE the user gets all the way to your WCF interface. So, if you were using client certificates, User/Password or Forms authentication, these forms of authentication are declared within the WCF endpoint definition. These forms of authentication challenge the user (in effect) before they even get to your ping() function, exposing a WCF authentication event during which you can check the client's credentials. This is good because it can help stop hackers from bombing your WCF service with denial of service attacks since the full request never gets processes without authentication. An example can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx.

The other method is more obvious: creating a normal WCF login() function, called by the client, during which the client program hands over the ID/password combination for a commplete check against your database or directory. This method, too, works with or without SSL. This is programmed like any other endpoint function ... nothing special here.

Both methods work with or without SSL. In either case, if the credentials are wrong, you can program the login() or authentication() routine to return any error or message your like, including a regular 401 Unauthorized error.